# Logged-in users getting logged out on some pages

Tags: users

Here's my problem. Some users are logged into Drupal. When they navigate through the website and hit certain pages, they get "logged out" until they navigate to another one, where they are logged in again.

Different users have different pages on which this is triggered.

If anyone has any kind of lead, let me know !

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue to me. The page for unauthenticated users is presented to the authenticated users. If they were really logged out, the sequential page visit would also be logged out. Are you running any type of caching?

Comment: This could be it @Neograph734 . The module Boost is installed. Wouldn't all users get the problem on the same pages tho ? They seem to experience it on each different "sets" of pages.

Comment: I've never used the Boost module, but it should only cache pages for anonymous users. Perhaps search the module's issue queue if it is a known problem? To see if it really is this module you can always try to disable it ;)

Comment: There is indeed some similar issues in the queue of the plugin. Thanks for making me realize that @Neograph734 ! :)